# When using infer on a generic type, why is the inferred type not resolved in the else of the ternary operator?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given a type which has a generic argument `T`:

`type Wrap<T> = { data: T };`

If I create a corresponding type to extract T:

`type Unwrap<W> = W extends Wrap<infer T> ? T : T;`

Why does `T` in the `else` result in the error: `Cannot find name 'T'`

I know it works with `never`, but this is a simplification where in reality I want to do something else with the second `T`

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7axek?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fform-model.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `T` wouldn't have anything to refer to in the false  branch of the conditional. If `Wrap<infer T>` isn't true, `T` couldn't be inferred; even if it existed, it would have no meaning. So it's only declared in the true branch, not the false one.

[The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) doesn't state that directly, but does only mention the inferred type being declared in the true branch. The [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) for v2.8 (when `infer` was introduced) are more direct about it:

> Within the `extends` clause of a conditional type, it is now possible to have `infer` declarations that introduce a type variable to be inferred. **Such inferred type variables may be referenced in the true branch of the conditional type.**

*(my emphasis)*

It still doesn't say *why*, so my rationale above is (ahem) inferred, but I think it's sound.

Answer (score 1):

if it doesn't extend `Wrap<T>` it can be anything, it can be a number, string, array or another object, in this case you can't know whatever it is, its any or never or unknown for you.

If there are limited options for example if W can be a Wrap or string you can write nested extends:

```
type Unwrap<W> = W extends Wrap<infer T> ? T : W extends string ? string : unknown;
```

After carefully rereading your question, i think you want to do this:

```
type Unwrap<W> = W extends Wrap<infer T> ? T : W;
```